# Jmeter - Using varible: from JDBC request into another JDBC query under loop

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, Based on the JDBC query id's i need to pass to another query, located under ForEach Controller.

1. Results return from query1

> ```
> url id
> https://pay1.com/ 1
> https://pay3.com/ 3
> https://pay8.com/ 8
> ```

Based on the ID returned, i need to pass to another query:

```
select *
FROM transaction  
WHERE id = '${id_1}'
```

If i try like: `${id_1}` or `${id_3}` is working fine.

But, how can i pass dynamically to the next query, without hard coding the index?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ForEach Controller has pre-defined variable exposing the current iteration, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named `__jm__<Name of your element>__idx`. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named `FEC`, then you can access the looping index through `${__jm__FEC__idx}`. Index starts at 0

So

- given your ForEach Controller name is `ForEach Controller` you can access its current loop as `${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx}`
- given indices are zero-based and your variables are 1-based you need to add 1 to the current index which can be done using [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) function
- and finally you will need to use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function in order to evaluate the resulting expression using your `id_` prefix

Putting everything together, the code you're looking for would be something like:

```
${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)