# Jmeter - Using varible: from JDBC request into JSR223 PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter

Based on this thread: [Jmeter - Using varible: from JDBC request into another JDBC query under loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066792/jmeter-using-varible-from-jdbc-request-into-another-jdbc-query-under-loop/62069218#62069218)

I tried to get variable from DB query and use it.

If i use into parameter value like: `${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}` inside loop controller works perfectly fine.

[image]

But, if i want to use in JSR223 PostProcessor like:

```
def dbID = '${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}'
log.warn(dbID);
```

or

```
def dbID = prop.getObject("id").get(i).get("id")
log.warn(dbID);
```

My script fails.

What is the equivalent usage of `${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}` into JSR223 PostProcessor?

My script:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vars`:

```
 int id = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("__jm__Loop Controller__idx"))+1;
 vars.get("id_"+ id);
```

Comment: When i try to use into PostProcessor, i got exception:Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
 at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]

Comment: @vlatko606 change Loop Controller to Controller name

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. Usage as: int id = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("__jm__Loop Controller__idx"))+1;
def ID = vars.get("id_"+ id);
log.warn(ID);